# OpenCV 3.0 Python, stitch and blend 2 images given Homography

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I have already computed Homography between two images. I can also stitch them fine i.e. I can choose which image to show on overlapped region. But I am doing it manually (pixel by pixel) and it is somewhat time consuming.

Is there a built-in function to do it? 
PLUS, I want to blend as well, I want a blend in overlap region.

Answer (score 0):

Though Its quite late but I'll answer the question for other people who might stumble to this post
You can use addweighted Function of opencv. The documentation is provided here at [Addweighted Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/dc4/tutorial_adding_images.html#gsc.tab=0).
This function combines two images linearly with the proportion being set by alpha and beta(1 - alpha) as shown below :

Ires = alpha * I1 + (1-alpha) * I2;

The code for the same  is shown below :

```
cv2.addweighted(orig1, alpha, orig2, (1- alpha), 0, output);
```

Here orig1 and orig2 are images to be blended.